# What MATLAB function can I use to add sound clips?

Tags: matlab, audio, signals, analysis

This is the code I have so far
I am stuck on Part F

```
% Project 1
% Part B

[S1,Fs1,bits] = wavread('F1');
[S3,Fs3,bits3] = wavread('F3');
[S6,Fs6,bits6] = wavread('F6');

S12=downsample(S1,2);
S32=downsample(S3,2);
S62=downsample(S6,2);

% Part D
%F1
L1=length(S1);       %Number of samples
F1=Fs1 ;             %Sampling Frequency
E1 =sum((S1).^2);    %Energy
P1=E1/L1;            %Power
%S12
L12=length(S12);     %Number of samples
F12=Fs1   ;          %Sampling Frequency
E12 =sum((S12).^2);  %Energy
P12=E12/L12     ;    %Power
%F6
L6=length(S6) ;      %Number of samples
F6=Fs6    ;          %Sampling Frequency
E6 =sum((S6).^2) ;   %Energy
P6=E6/L6   ;         %Power
%S62
L62=length(S62);     %Number of samples
F62=Fs6;             %Sampling Frequency
E62 =sum((S62).^2);  %Energy
P62=E62/L62;         %Power

% L1 = 93648
% F1 = 22050
% E1 = 1.3476e+03
% P1 = 0.0144
% L12 = 46824
% F12 = 22050
% E12 = 673.5918
% P12 = 0.0144
% L6 = 5934
% F6 = 22050
% E6 = 34.8697
% P6 = 0.0059
% L62 = 2967
% F62 = 22050
% E62 = 17.4075
% P62 = 0.0059

% Part E

S14=downsample(S1,4);

% Part F
[S2,Fs2,bits2] = wavread('F2');
[S4,Fs4,bits4] = wavread('F4');
[S5,Fs5,bits5] = wavread('F5');
[S7,Fs7,bits7] = wavread('F7');
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I want to add the clips S2,S6,S4,S5,S3,S7,S7.

What function should I use?
I have been searching for awhile with no luck.

This was the problem posed to me for this part of the code:

How can you generate a new signal (F8) which contains the word “remember”  followed by 0.2 second of silence, and then followed by the sentence “you will be with force, always, always”

Comment: What do you mean by "add the clips"? You want to create a new clip that would sound like the others played on top of each other?

Comment: His task is to concatenate some audio, or some silence into some audio

Comment: Well, he hasn't said what each clip is, but sound clips are just vectors and you concatenate them as you would any vector [a, b]. Also, meaningful variable names are your friend.

Comment: Each clip is a word. adding the clips/files is meant to order the words one after the other. after the second word, there needs to be a 0.2second pause.

Answer (score 0):

As you might know everything in matlab is about vectors (S2,S3,... are vectors indeed), so you can just concatenate them:
You could use `c = vertcat(S2,S3,...)` for vertical concatenation or `c = horzcat(S2,S3,...)` for horizontal concatenation

Comment: I wouldn't simply concatenate sound clips - doing so will result in discontinuities that can be heard as "clicks" or "pops".

Comment: Each clip is a word. adding the clips/files is meant to order the words one after the other. after the second word, there needs to be a 0.2second pause.

Comment: It won't let me upvote, but this was helpful. I just can't figure out how to add a 0.2 second pause

Comment: @user2011410 A 0.2 second pause can be implemented by adding a (roughly) DC level between the two samples. Say the first clip has the last sample at level N1, and the next clip has a sample level starting at N2, then create 0.2 seconds worth of linearly spaced points between N1 and N2, and concatenate these between the clips.